# How to manage user content in django?

Tags: python, django

I want manage user posts. When someone create new post it's should display on admin, but not on html. If content is valid i want push on allow button and it will display on html for all users. i was try to google something, but nothing helpfull. I suppose logic must be like this:

1. User create new post.
2. Post displayed on admin panel.
3. Admin allow the post.
4. Post displayed in html.

How it should work?

Comment: add boolean field is_draft default false [booleanfield](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#booleanfield) `models.BooleanField(default=False)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment of [Bear Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8060120/bear-brown) in code.

`models.py`:

```
class Post(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)        
     content = models.TextField()
     is_draft = models.BooleanField(help_text='If checked article gets not published.', default=False)
     pub_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)

     objects = PublishedManager()
```

Query via e.g. `Django` shell:

```
Post.objects.filter(is_draft=False)
```

`managers.py` additional filter to return only objects with a `pub_date` which is lower than or equals the current date:

```
class PublishedManager(models.Manager):

    def published(self, **kwargs):
        return self.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now(),
                           is_draft=False,
                           **kwargs).order_by('-pub_date')
```

`views.py`:

```
class PostListView(ListView):    
    model = Post

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Post.objects.published()
        return queryset
```

template:

```
{% for post in post_list %}
  <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
  {{ post.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yes, manager it's a good idea

Answer (score 0):

Adding an `is_published` field to your model is somehow a quick solution if you only need this and you know that you will not need anything else in the future (for example `needs_editing`). Most of the times, those needs multiply quickly and you get yourself into a vicious circle of complicated code that is not easy to follow.

[Django-FSM](https://github.com/kmmbvnr/django-fsm) is a module that tackles exactly with this issue in a clean and DRY manner. A nice introduction can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/Nagyman/9502133).

> Definitely avoid ...
>
> Booleans for states
>
> ```
> is_new
> is_active
> is_published
> is_draft
> is_deleted
> is_paid
> is_member
> is_*
> ```
>
> Mutually exclusive states ... sort of finite, but the number of states
>   increases with each bool:
>
> ```
> 2 bools = 2^2 = 4 states
> 3 bools = 2^3 = 8 states
> etc (2^N)
> ```
>
> Brittle and too many states to check.